# JSON data is shown as promise

Tags: json, python-2.7, vue.js, flask, promise

my vue js code

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({   
  state: {},
  getters: {
    changeempdatas: (state) => {
      var apidata =Vue.axios.post ('http://127.0.0.1:5000/').then( (response) => {
                 return response.data
               });                              
      var changeempdatas = apidata.then(function(result) {
            console.log(result.empdata)             
            return result.empdata;                  
      })
      console.log(changeempdatas)
      return changeempdatas;            
    }
  }
});
```

and my python code

```
 conn= pymysql.connect
(host='127.0.0.1',user='root',password='',
db='test')
class senddata(Resource):
def post(self):
    curr = conn.cursor()
    getdataqry = curr.execute("SELECT * 
    FROM `employee`")
    getdatas = curr.fetchall()
    #empdata = []
    print "Post"
    i=0
    empdata = {}
    for getdata in getdatas:
        i += 1
        empdata[i] = {}
        empdata[i]['id'] = getdata[0]
        empdata[i]['name'] = getdata[1]
        #empdata.append({'id': getdata[0], 
    'name': getdata[1]})

    return jsonify({'empdata': empdata})
    a.close()
```

The JSON data from python is not received as JSON, It shows as a promise. How can I call the JSON data as normal JSON?

[response output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UFP3.png)

Comment: You should be [using an `action`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) in Vuex to do your asynchronous work. Your getter should just work with the state.

Comment: no i didn't use action

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue, but what I can tell from your code is that the returned `return changeempdatas;` is a promise, not the plain data.

Comment: Also note that you can use promise chaining to make your code more readable.

Comment: The result.empdata return normal json data but when it comes out of the scope it became promise.